# is this sentence grammatically correct? What does it mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

In the sentence below, I don't understand how the clause after "over and above.." fit into the sentence.

> people who eat diets high in processed foods are taking an equivalent of 11, 1-g capsules of linoleic acid daily over and above intake from wholesome foods

Is it basically saying, if you eat a lot of processed foods, it's like taking 11 capsules of linoleic acid (1g per capsule) and this is a lot more than the intake from whole some foods?

and

what would be a synonym for "wholesome foods"? What does wholesome mean in this case?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wholesome), wholesome is:

1. promoting health or well-being of mind or spirit
2. promoting health of body
3. sound in body, mind, or morals, having the simple health or vigor of normal domesticity
4. based on well-grounded fear, safe

And as for the first question, it seems about right.